# Filemaker -- Scripting import from .fmp12 using update fields and matching names?

Tags: scripting, filemaker

I'm trying to properly script importing a daily database into a master database.

Everything in the script I have currently works just fine, except for the import step.

I want to:

arrange by matching names
update matching records in found set
add remaining data as new records
and I want to set my matching field to the UUID in my database.
dialog off

I've found that when importing via script, filemaker doesn't really let you do "matching names" and set the matching field.

I've resorted to setting the script to use Last Order and manually importing a sample file before I do a batch of imports via script. Kind of a pain, and not a solid solution for me to share with my coworkers.

ANY help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use the FileMaker Data Migration tool to import matching files into eachother. The migration tool will do the best effort to match fields based on their internal id first, and their name second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import Records using matching fields AND matching records is - sadly - not possible.

The best you can do is make it work 'for now' - as Siva describes - PLUS mark the script, so you remember to update the script EVERY TIME you add/change your fields! :-/

For example: We use the flag "#**NF**#" in script names for scripts that need to be edited when we add a **N**ew **F**ield

I made exactly this feature request to Claris in 2017: see [Import records with matching field names AND update matching records](https://community.claris.com/en/s/idea/0870H000000fyjVQAQ/detail)

Please vote it up, shout it up + discuss, in order to (maybe) get it implemented by Claris.

Answer (score 2):

Select "Matching Names" option. It will match the names of both tables. Then select the UUID field option as "Match records based on this field". Now the "Matching Names" automatically changed to "Custom Order". It will still remember the field mapping.

Comment: Oh that's a bummer. Matching Names would be  a bit more future proof. If new fields get added in the future, a static custom order would miss them.